# TikZ: Move points towards center

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations, pgfmath

I want to move a set of points towards the center of my figure,
but I want the distance to depend inversely on the relative distance to the center.
Thus, for instance move a point at (-2,-3) to ( -2 - 1/(-2), -3 - 1/(-3) ).

If have my x- and y-points in a list, which I iterate over, but when I try to divide with on if them it results in a "division by 0" error.
Substituting e.g. \x in -1/\x with -8 to -1/-8 the division works perfectly.

So my question is: How can I parse \x and \y correctly to the division?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x/\y  in {-8/2,-8/-4,-6/5,-7/7,-4/-6,-1/5,-3/-2,-3.5/2.5,%
                    0/-7,.5/8,6/-3,7/2,4/-8,1/-5,3/5,9/7}%
    {
        \filldraw [white, draw=black, dashed] (\x,\y) circle (.75);
        \shadedraw [ball color=red, very thin] ({\x-1/\x},{\y-1/\y}) circle (.5);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I completely missed that. Changing the x-position (since it isn't that important) solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: If you saw my last comment, ignore it. My code didn't give the right results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your `\x`s is `0`. TeX cannot divide by 0 so this is never going to work. Try substituting e.g. `\x` in `-1/x` with `0` to give `-1/0` and it will not work even imperfectly!

If you substitute `0.1` for `0`, it does work perfectly:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x/\y  in {-8/2,-8/-4,-6/5,-7/7,-4/-6,-1/5,-3/-2,-3.5/2.5,%
                    0.1/-7,.5/8,6/-3,7/2,4/-8,1/-5,3/5,9/7}%
    {
        \filldraw [white, draw=black, dashed] (\x,\y) circle (.75);
        \shadedraw [ball color=red, very thin] ({\x-1/\x},{\y-1/\y}) circle (.5);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```